# subfig package gives error "Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}" error in beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I’m getting an error with loading subfig package for beamer document class. It gives an error “Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}”.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code from which I made this MWE used to work fine a few months ago.

Comment: No error here. Since the error occurred around the `\begin{document}` area (at the end of the preamble), it may be related to a previous compile since that's when the `.aux` is read in. Perhaps delete all auxiliary files generated by your compilation and try again.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. Deleting the aux did not solve the issue. I ran this code in three machines, it did not run in two and ran in the third one. I initially found a bypass by adding 
\makeatletter
\let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax
\makeatother
to the preamble. Later, upon suggestion from a colleague. I updated tex live on Mac and the issue went away.

Comment: Duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426088/36296